# Authenticate user then send JWT and serve angular app

Tags: angular, express

I have an angular app which only certain users (e.g. employees) can use.

I want to do something like this:

- user GETs `/employees/login`
- server responds with server-rendered login page (e.g. `ejs` or `pug` - not angular)
- user POSTs form to `/employees/login`
- server authenticates user
- *...here is the problem... respond with JWT and also serve angular app (`express.static(...)`)*

I know how to respond with a JWT and get angular to put it in localstorage. I also know how to respond with a statically-served angular app.

But I don't know how to do both those things together, given that angular is not yet running in the browser.

How do I do this? I don't need code, just an explanation how this is done. There are no official docs for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is as follows:

- Server side app hosts API and returns 401/403 for unauthenticated/unauthorized requests
- Angular app (module run function) makes a call to a profile endpoint to get details of current user (will return as above if user hasn't logged in). This is what forces the user authentication immediately, rather than waiting for an API call.
- Angular app has an http interceptor that looks for 401/403 responses and redirects to server side login page, with requested client-side route asa parameter so that we can redirect neck to the correct place on successful login
- Server side login page has code that - on successful login - inserts JWT into localStorage and then handles the redirect (via page JavaScript, nothing to do with Angular).

Comment: Thanks Nat! I'm not sure I follow though... I don't want to serve the angular app until the user is authenticated (logged in). I only want employees to be able to load that app (there is a separate angular app for public users/customers). Basically I want to login on a server-rendered page, and then get access to the angular app and the JWT. Hope I'm explaining myself well?

Comment: You are doing, yeah. You could still do that with your server side view? On successful login you can add the JWT to localStorage *and* serve the view that contains angular script references etc? If your API is secure though, does it matter that the angular app is loading and perhaps telling the user that they're not authenticated?

Comment: You'll need to consider users hitting refresh on your Angular pages too. If they do that, the browser won't include the JWT in the headers of the page request and they'll be redirected to login page.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean. I could have a "bootstrapping" bit of javascript/jquery on the employee login page, which send the ajax/XHR request to the server, receives a JWT in return as well as the link to the app download page, store the jwt in localstorage, then redirect to the app download page. By then the user is authenticated, so he'll be able to load that page, and thus, the angular app. Sounds reasonable to you?

Comment: Yeah, perfectly reasonable :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping me reason through this! Never thought I'd need to use jQuery again... :)

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. You can definitely do it without jQuery - bit of native script should be enough!